# Android -Stuck with Bundles

Tags: java, android

I have three Activities in my Android Application.Activity A ,Activity B,Activity C..

In Activity A ,I'm doing the Json Parsing and I send that values to Activity B using Bundles and handle that in many ways .

here is the code I used in Activity B to get values.

```
        Intent in = getIntent();
    Bundle b = in.getExtras();


    /*/----------Future Use ---------------------
    String id1 = b.getString("id");
    String mc1 = b.getString("machine_code");

    ------------------------------------------/*/


    String di1 = b.getString("di1");
    String di2 = b.getString("di2");
    String di3 = b.getString("di3");
    String di4 = b.getString("di4");
    String di5 = b.getString("di5");
    String di6 = b.getString("di6");
    String di7 = b.getString("di7");
    String di8 = b.getString("di8");
```

In Activity B .I've a button to move to Activity C and in Activity C  ,I've Back Button to move to Activity B again .

My problem is When When I go back from Activity C to B.My App force closes suddenly .

My logcat Error is given below.

```
03-25 11:22:31.699: E/AndroidRuntime(307): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gprs/com.example.gprs.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at com.example.gprs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:175)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
03-25 11:22:31.719: E/AndroidRuntime(307):  ... 11 more
03-25 11:22:31.760: I/dalvikvm(307): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
03-25 11:22:31.760: E/dalvikvm(307): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
03-25 11:22:37.569: I/Process(307): Sending signal. PID: 307 SIG: 9
```

In logcat you can see the MainActivity(which is Activity B)

Comment: post your mainactivity class and mention line no 175.

Comment: NullPointerException... Try covering your code with try..catch statements,.. Are you passing the same things from C to B which are done at the time of A to B..? May be on back button, puExtra can work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `Bundle b = in.getExtras();` returns `null` when you come back to `Activity B` from `Activity C`.

First case, you are sending the `bundle` from `Activity A` to `Activity B`, but when coming from `Activity C`, I don't think you're sending the `bundle` in the `intent`. And hence, when you try to `String di1 = b.getString("di1");` from a `null`(Bundle b), you'll get the `NullPointerException`.

Have a **null** check before trying to access `bundle` in the `Activity B`.

Answer (score 0):

> I've Back Button to move to Activity B again

You are not following android app guidlines. There shouldn't be back button at all.I am quite sure your application is breaking while doing `intent.getExtras()`

Answer (score 0):

You have a nullpointer exception at line 175 (at com.example.gprs.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:175)

Can you post what is there ? I guess it's related to the Bundle. You must to store your values when onSaveInstanceState is called on activity B and read it onRestoreInstance state and always check if your bundle is null or not before trying to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

**This is because of your bundle is null**

```
bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();

if (b!=null) {
  // your code
}
```